# OSError when running roscore

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and trying to install everything correctly and test that roscore is working. I know there are previous questions like this, but none were able to fix my problem. I get the following error messages when running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 279, in start
    self.runner.launch()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 654, in launch
    self._setup()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 630, in _setup
    self._launch_master()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 394, in _launch_master
    validate_master_launch(m, self.is_core, self.is_rostest)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 83, in validate_master_launch
    if not rosgraph.network.is_local_address(m.get_host()):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 176, in is_local_address
    local_addresses = ['localhost'] + get_local_addresses()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 219, in get_local_addresses
    for iface in netifaces.interfaces():
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261492/oserror-when-running-roscore/) by [njames8](https://answers.ros.org/users/30335/njames8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-11**:
Can you clarify which OS this is? If this is Win10 with WSL, make sure to run a very recent build.

**Comment by [njames8](https://answers.ros.org/users/30335/njames8/) on 2017-05-11**:
Yes Windows 10 and I got Ubuntu. Not sure why python is in the error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q238646. You'll need to run a really recent Win10 build. Possibly even at least the Creators Update or an insiders build.

---

Also: could you please for the future remember to *always* mention at least the OS that you are running, and in cases of Win10/WSL mention that? I know the idea is that WSL is as-close-as-possible (sort-of) to a regular Linux kernel+userland, but that is not the case right now and there are multiple areas in which bugs/unimplemented features in WSL actually cause problems with software that otherwise is perfectly ok.

Without such information we cannot help you.

---

Edit:

> Not sure why python is in the error messages

Well .. `roscore` and large parts of ROS are written in Python, so that would explain it.

---

Edit2:

> Could you please explain what a recent Win10 build is and how I can get this correctly installed on my machine? Sorry, I'm very new to ROS.

This is not really a ROS-issue: Windows 10 is currently still being developed and the problem you report is in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). The ability to use the *Bash shell* as MS calls it was only added in relatively recent releases of Windows 10. The problem is that it is not a finished piece of functionality. Lots of things are still missing. Especially pieces that ROS needs to work under Win10/WSL.

Only in very recent releases has WSL matured enough for it to run ROS successfully. And most of those releases are not available without being on the Windows Insider program, and then specifically in the *fast ring*.

Bare-bones ROS appears to work relatively ok on Windows 10 build 16188, which was only released a week ago (2017-05-04). The error message that you included in your post suggests to me that you are on a relatively old release of Windows 10, as that specific issue was resolved in WSL a couple of releases ago.

To check which version you are running: `win + r`, then type `winver` and press enter. The dialogue that pops up should tell you the version and the build.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [njames8](https://answers.ros.org/users/30335/njames8/) on 2017-05-11**:
Could you please explain what a recent Win10 build is and how I can get this correctly installed on my machine? Sorry, I'm very new to ROS..

**Comment by [njames8](https://answers.ros.org/users/30335/njames8/) on 2017-05-11**:
I looked at the referenced question above and couldnt really understand where to go from here

**Comment by [njames8](https://answers.ros.org/users/30335/njames8/) on 2017-05-11**:
Mine is: Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.1198). So I need a newer build correct? If so, how can I get that? Thanks again for the help!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-11**:
Yes, you need a much more recent build. Yours is almost ancient (when it comes to WSL at least). As this is really no longer a ROS issue, I would advise you to search around a bit for how to get into the Insiders program. Be aware of all the consequences of that though.